# Esta questão é uma revisão de código?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica

Esta questão me parece revisão de código:

- [Como poderia melhorar o código?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/78666/3635)

Acredito que este tipo de pergunta seja aceita aqui no SOpt, mas estou em dúvida, já apareceu duas vezes na fila pra fechar (acho que rejeitaram o fechamento e depois outra pessoa tentou fechar, ou só apareceu porque eu "pulei" ela, não tenho certeza).

Adicionei a tag [revisão-código](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revis%c3%a3o-c%c3%b3digo), mas se eu estiver enganado me comunique para poder fazer o rollback.

Comment: acho muito válido esse tipo de pergunta. Sou contra fechamento desses tipos de perguntas.

Comment: Se fossemos o SOen essa pergunta seria movida para http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ , mas como não temos o programadores.stackexchange.com e o SOpt aceita, essa revisão é bem vinda.

Comment: @GuilhermeJSantos Não sei acho que na verdade seria movida para o http://codereview.stackexchange.com ... Já sobre o SOpt, o escopo que aceitamos aqui é um pouco mais amplo que o do SOen.

Comment: Relacionado: [revisão-código é uma meta tag?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2594/3117)

Comment: Particularmente, acho que este tipo de pergunta deveria vir com uma atenção maior do autor, que apenas colou o código e pediu opiniões. Não foi explicado o que é esperado do código, nem se existe algum ponto específico que ele espera melhora (desempenho, formatação, possibilidade de erros, enfim). Mas me parece que a comunidade considera a pergutna boa, já que recebeu 3 respostas e está com pontuação + 4.

Comment: @Molx sim faz sentido o que você disse, no entanto a revisão estava em base de coisas que ele parecia não entender. Talvez ela esteja mais voltada ao uso da linguagem do que a qualquer outra coisa. Vendo as resposta vai notar que teve mais dicas sobre `if` e `while` do que outra coisa. Talvez isto ficou mais claro a que respondeu. Note que o motivo que criei está pergunta no META é praticamente o mesmo que o seu, a pergunta não parece uma "revisão de código", já que falta detalhes. E parece que sinalizaram ela duas vezes (não tenho certeza).

Comment: um adendo, a única coisa que não gosto nessas perguntas é o título.. geralmente sempre o mesmo título... podemos ter 1 milhão de perguntas "como melhorar..." e cada uma com contextos completamente diferente.. Acho que o autor poderia elaborar melhor os títulos, pelo menos.

Comment: @DanielOmine realmente o título ficou ruim :/ - mas como colaboradores podemos sempre melhorar :)